# Can't call controls in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView element which has an ItemTemplate within it which has an Image element within it also that I can't access in the code for some reason, is their a way to do this?

```
<div class="container">
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<h4><%# Eval("colour") + " " + Eval("make") + " " + Eval("model") + " " + "(" + Eval("type") + ")"%></h4>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" class="main" runat="server" />
<div class="caption">
<h4><div class="title"> Seller: </div><%# Eval("first_name") + " " + Eval("last_name")%></h4>
<h4><div class="title"> Location: </div><%# Eval("city") %></h4>
<h4><div class="title"> Year Of Reg: </div><%# Eval("year") %></h4>
<h4><div class="title"> Price: </div><%# "£" + Eval("price") %></h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</div>
```

I am trying to call the Image1 in code.

I want to access it on a click event, however the ID is not showing when I try access the control, here is my click event:

```
 protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: when do u want to access it, on databound, onclick or ....?

Comment: @Legends Sorry about that, updated!

Comment: ok, but which item do you want from the list? You need to know that, for example the first item, you would do it like this:
    `ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("Image1") as Image;`

Comment: @Legends This is the error I get with it, "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: post the code, to see what u r doing.

Comment: It's fine, I declared a var, please post it as an answer so i can mark it as correct @Legends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the index of the listview item from which you want to access the image, then you can do the following:

```
ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("Image1") as Image;
```